# How to set same filter value to be searched to the different filters on the same page?

Tags: views

I am using 3 exposed filter on same page for video, audio and album search, what I want is when I enter filter criteria for one filter all filters should take same filter criteria. Is there anyone who is having an idea to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enter the same identifier for all views, if you want to use one exposed value for all views in current page.

[image]